Imgur API rate limit on OVH hosting
I have a Python code that uploads pictures to Imgur, receiving them through a telegram bot, I get an exception imgurpython.helpers.error.ImgurClientRateLimitError: Rate-limit exceeded!
If I run the code on my computer, everything works great, but on my hosting (OVH) everything breaks
I connected to OpenVpn which runs through my hosting and ran the same code on my computer and it gave the same error. So I guess the problem is in the IP address
